# Effect of varying length of solenoid coil on magnetic flux

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Given the number of turns (N) and current is constant for any cross section of the coil, does varying the length of the coil not have any effect on the magnetic flux in the centre of the coil?

i.e. a coil 1 wire thick has just the same flux in the centre as when surrounded on both side by another bunch of coils also?

Comment: Number of turns $N$ is single number characterizing the whole solenoid, it makes no sense to say it is constant for any cross section. Did you mean constant coil density per unit length?

Comment: Also when talking about magnetic flux in context of solenoids, we usually mean total magnetic flux through the whole winding, so it does not depend on position. So again it makes no sense to say "magnetic flux in the centre of the coil".

Comment: @JánLalinský Yes, constant coil density per unit length

Comment: @JánLalinský The thing is, the iron object I want to apply an EM force to, is smaller than the wire diameter - hence will it experience a higher force from the coil, if the coil is longer (all else being equal)?

Comment: The longer the coil, the greater the region with magnetic field that is inside the coil, but magnetic field does not get stronger, as it is proportional to coil density per unit length and current.